# URL Rewriting Works but PHP doesnt take variable with GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, get

Im having some issues with my htaccess rewriting rules after a server move.

For any reason my old directive is not working any more.

My htacess has the following line:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ads/mobile/([a-z0-9_-]+)/?$ /ads.php?ptid=6&tube_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

I dont get any 500 or 404 error.
The url bar shows the url in rewrite mode OK,
but php doesnt take the GET var from the rewritten url.

If I access to ads.php with the vars on the url, it works perfect.

Any idea?
I changed  from NC,L to QSA and also I deleted the "/" before ads.php but nothing works.

I will aprreciate any help. I searched for something similar here but nothing works for me.

Comment: Note: mod_rewrite is enable in apache

Comment: This is n working example `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`, if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was my fault.
It didnt work because I didnt change from NONE to ALL the allowoverride settings on the file /etc/apache2/(site)

It works now! 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is most likely due to enabling of `MultiViews` option.

Turn it off by putting this line on top of your `.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews
```